# Select all rows expect previous and next day data of a specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have got a table like this

```
kpl_id     Process_date         baseline_date
----------------------------------------------------
20        2018-04-12 02:00:00         NULL
21        2018-04-13 02:01:00         NULL
22        2018-04-14 02:02:00         NULL
23        2018-04-16 09:15:00         2018-04-17 10:23:00
24        2018-04-16 17:15:00         NULL
25        2018-04-17 02:00:00         NULL
26        2018-04-18 02:00:00         NULL
--------------------------------------------------
```

My requirement is to select all rows except baseline_day and its next and previous days.

So output looks like this

```
kpl_id     Process_date         baseline_date
----------------------------------------------------
20        2018-04-12 02:00:00         NULL
21        2018-04-13 02:01:00         NULL
26        2018-04-18 02:00:00         NULL
--------------------------------------------------
```

I tried below query which I believe its a wrong approach.

```
select Pl.* from process_log_temp PL left outer join
(select *,dateadd(day,-2,baseline_created) d1,dateadd(day,2,baseline_created) d2 from process_log_temp where baseline_created is not null) PL2 on PL2.kpl_id=PL.kpl_id
where  PL.process_date between d1 and d2
```

and of course it returned only baselines day which I was not expecting

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/100dcf) with all rows

Environment is SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you find the `baseline_date` and then from there get the previous and next date. After that just select from the table excluding that date range

```
WITH baseline AS
(
  SELECT [process_date],
         [prev_date] = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [process_date])),
         [next_date] = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, +1, [process_date]))
  FROM   [process_log_temp]
  WHERE  [baseline_created] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM   process_log_temp p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   baseline x
           WHERE  p.[process_date] > x.[prev_date]
           AND    p.[process_date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, x.[next_date])
       )
```

---

EDIT-1:
New requirement

> if baseline on 22 and if there is no data in 21st, then requirement is
> to skip data of 20th as well

Sounds like you want to based on row rather than date

```
WITH process AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = row_number() over (order by [process_date])
  FROM   [process_log_temp]    
)
SELECT *
FROM   process p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   process x
           WHERE  x.baseline_created IS NOT NULL
           AND    p.rn >= x.rn - 1
           AND    p.rn <= x.rn + 1
       )
```

---

EDIT-2 : for multiple entry of same day, use `dense_rank()` and convert the `process_date` to date for ordering

```
rn = dense_rank() over (order by convert(date, [process_date]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works great. but I am facing a little challenge there when there is no data on the previous day of baseline. For example if baseline on 22 and if there is no data in 21st, then requirement is to skip data of 20th as well. Could you please suggest a way to solve that? In my sample in the question kpl_id 22 is like that which is required to skip. But with this query it wont exclude

Comment: My query does not include kpl_id 22 in the result at all. What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great. But I am facing a little challenge when there are multiple entry on same day.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/885d7/1

Comment: see updated query

Comment: You are awesome boss!!